# Files copied with batch script disappear from folder once terminal is closed

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Right now I'm trying to work on a batch script that will take files from one directory, rename them, and copy them into another directory. It's incredibly simple but I'm running into a strange problem where the script will copy and rename files appropriately, but as soon as the terminal closes and the script terminates, the files disappear as if nothing was used.

```
REM displays as mmddyyyy
set copy_date=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%

set file_path=C:\wkspace\dir\files\
set archive_path=C:\wkspace\archive\files

Call :copy_files_to_archive
pause

:copy_files_to_archive
set dir_list=\dir1 \dir2 \dir3 \dir4
for %%i in (%dir_list%) do (
if %%i==\dir1 (
copy "%file_path%%%i_filename_%copy_date%.xml" "%archive_path%\sub_dir%%i_filename-ARCHIVED_%copy_date%.xml"
)
if %%i==\dir2 (
... the same code is repeated for the rest of the files through \dir4
)
)
EXIT /B 0
```

Like I said earlier, the files are showing up in the target directory and they're renamed. But when I hit any key in the terminal to close it, all of the files just disappear. They aren't hidden or anything so I'm stumped.

**Just a note: I stripped this code down to only focus on one file because it's repetitive. Focusing on the one file should fix my problem**

All help is appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "terminal"?  Are we talking about a local console window or something else?

Comment: Yes the local console window. The one that opens up when the script is running.

Comment: Are `c:\wkspace` and `c:\wkspace\archive` just plain old local directories, or are there drive or path mappings taking place for your console instance?

Comment: Well right now they're only local directories, but this will get loaded onto a server eventually and I'm assuming I'll have to touch it up as needed.

Comment: And the console environment isn't a container of some kind?

Comment: not that I'm aware of.. but can you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: In your copy statement it looks like you are trying to copy a file into a file, check `copy /?`, also, why are you using call :thing instead to goto if you aren't passing any arguments?

Comment: To my knowledge, that's simply renaming the file in the target folder.

is there another way to copy and rename in the same step?

Comment: Ah, indeed you are correct, my mistake.

Comment: Will it change if you use goto :eof instead of `exit /b 0`? Sometimes error codes in batch script mess up the changes if they were global

Comment: This script is on my work laptop, let me recreate it on my home computer and get back to you!

Comment: @NekoMusume I tried running it both ways with goto :eof and exit /b 0 on my home computer and it didn't affect it either way..

Comment: I'm starting to think it might just be a problem with how access is set up on my work laptop.. maybe I can try running as admin and that would fix it? if that doesn't work I'm not sure why else the files would just delete themselves after the console window closes

Comment: We have some pretty advanced AI protection on our computers at work.  It basically learns as it goes. When we first implemented it, it was pretty rough as it was thinking just about everything was a threat.  But as we tweaked some settings and it figured stuff out, it learned what was a threat and what wasn't. So I would check if you have any threat protection that may be quarantining the files.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that `%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%` outputs a valid string for a Windows path. It seems to expact that your current `%DATE%` variable looks similar to this format, `DOW MM/DD/YYYY`, (for example `Fri 04/24/2020`). If you have a different format, for your `%DATE%` variable, then the date separators are probably included in that string, making it invalid, and hence nothing copied!

Comment: @Compo yes the date variable works fine. %date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4% strips down the current date to only month, day, and year without any special characters between. I took this code and ran it in a batch script on my home computer and the files I moved persisted after the console window closed. It's a tricky question, because I'm almost positive my code isn't the issue now

Comment: I'm a little unsure based upon your answer, @NathanSampson, whether you've identified that it works on your 'home computer' because its `%DATE%` variable provides the required output, and that it doesn't on your work laptop, because it has a different output. The variable produces different output for different locales, and languages and its readily configurable on every PC. Can you confirm that the computer exhibiting the issue, has exactly the output format, `DOW MM/DD/YYYY`? or not?

Comment: @Compo the date variable should not be the issue. From my work and home computers, I hit WindowsKey+R > entered 'cmd' > pasted this in "set copy_date=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%" > run 'echo %copy_date% and it displays mmddyyyy. You can try it for yourself if you'd like

Comment: **I cannot, @NathanSampson, _because I do not use a PC**_! However, on the PC's I work on predominantly, in my country, the vast majority produce a date formatted thus: `DD/MM/YYYY`, which using your splitting method, `Echo %DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~10,4%` would output, `4/02`, which would exhibit exactly the behavior I'm trying to explain. The forward slash is an illegal character in a file or directory name in Windows!